# Redirect-After-Post Form Result

Tags: node.js

What is the best way to display results after a "Redirect-After-Post" in NodeJS?

I'm doing this as follows: I pass a query to the url displaying the result-id.

Example:

```
// Route Post
res.redirect ('/recover?result=success'); // OK
res.redirect ('/recover?result=error'); // Error

// Route GET
if (req.query.result === 'success') {
     res.render(...);
}
```

I've been researching on this subject, in PHP many save the result in cookies (session), but I found this method I implemented simpler and more practical.

My question is, is it good practice? Would you have a more practical method?